# Android back arrow has no visual feedback on click

Tags: android

When I click on the back arrow, it works fine. But Google Apps have a visual effect showing a rounded dark circle. How can I add this?

[image]

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@id/toolbar"
    style="?attr/toolBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
```

**icn_navigation_back.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:viewportWidth="48.0"
        android:viewportHeight="48.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M19.8,23l5.59,-5.59l-1.41,-1.41l-8,8l8,8l1.41,-1.41l-5.59,-5.59l12.17,0l0,-2z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#003B5A"
        android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

The **icn_navigation_back** is loaded into an ImageView:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_navigation_button"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Comment: How did you init the icon?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i've edited the question. It's an ImageView.

Comment: You could use the standard icon using getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below attribute in Toolbar Item:

```
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use default action bar instead. In activity's `onCreate()`, just call: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //show arrow left icon`

Now I have a bar with arrow left item that has visual effect when pressed.

When I need custom the bar more but keep the arrow icon, I use

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.my_custom_view);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //show arrow left icon
```